# Using ldap to connect to ad with devise ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, active-directory

Question I am having issues connecting to my Microsoft Active Directory using the devise_ldap_authentication. For some reason I keep getting LDAP search yielded 0 matches when using it with devise and I am 100% certain I am using the correct credentials, so I wrote a test class using 'net/ldap' to see if I could yeild a correct match and presto it works with my test class but, I still can't authenticate with devise_ldap_auth. Any help would be greatly appreciated or help with setting up my config/ldap.yml to match my test class.

Here is my config/ldap.yml

```
#Environment
development:
  host: myldap.mydomain.com
  port: 389
  attribute: sAMAccountname
  base: dc=mydomain, dc=com
  admin_user: cn=admin,dc=mydomain,dc=com
  admin_password: password
  #ssl: false
```

Here is my devise.rb

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  # ==> LDAP Configuration
  config.ldap_logger = true
  # config.ldap_create_user = false
  # config.ldap_update_password = true
  config.ldap_config = "#{Rails.root}/config/ldap.yml"
  # config.ldap_check_group_membership = false
  # config.ldap_check_group_membership_without_admin = false
  config.ldap_check_attributes = true
  #config.ldap_use_admin_to_bind = true
  # config.ldap_ad_group_check = false
```

## this is what I get back when using ldap with devise.

```
D, [2016-06-24T07:01:30.558440 #42760] DEBUG -- :   LDAP: LDAP dn lookup: sAMAccountName=snow
D, [2016-06-24T07:01:30.558507 #42760] DEBUG -- :   LDAP: LDAP dn lookup: sAMAccountName=snow
D, [2016-06-24T07:01:30.558549 #42760] DEBUG -- :   LDAP: LDAP search for login: sAMAccountName=snow
D, [2016-06-24T07:01:30.558579 #42760] DEBUG -- :   LDAP: LDAP search for login: sAMAccountName=snow
D, [2016-06-24T07:01:30.594029 #42760] DEBUG -- :   LDAP: LDAP search yielded 0 matches
D, [2016-06-24T07:01:30.594099 #42760] DEBUG -- :   LDAP: LDAP search yielded 0 matches
D, [2016-06-24T07:01:30.594146 #42760] DEBUG -- :   LDAP: Authorizing user sAMAccountName=snow,dc=mydomain, dc=com
D, [2016-06-24T07:01:30.594180 #42760] DEBUG -- :   LDAP: Authorizing user sAMAccountName=snow,dc=mydomain, dc=com
D, [2016-06-24T07:01:30.611308 #42760] DEBUG -- :   LDAP: Not authorized because not authenticated.
D, [2016-06-24T07:01:30.611377 #42760] DEBUG -- :   LDAP: Not authorized because not authenticated.
```

Here is my test class that works to authenticate with ldap on my microsoft AD

```
require 'net/ldap' # gem install ruby-net-ldap
module Test
  class PutAd
    SERVER = 'myldap.mydomain.com'
    PORT = 389
    BASE = 'DC=mydomain,DC=com'
    DOMAIN = 'mydomain.com'

    ATTR_SV = {
                :login => :samaccountname,
                :first_name => :givenname,
                :last_name => :sn,
                :email => :mail
              }


    def self.authenticate(login, pass)
      return nil if login.empty? or pass.empty?

      conn = Net::LDAP.new :host => SERVER,
                           :port => PORT,
                           :base => BASE,
                           :auth => { :username => "#{login}@#{DOMAIN}",
                                      :password => pass,
                                      :method => :simple }
      if conn.bind and user = conn.search(:filter => "sAMAccountName=#{login}").first
        return self.new(user)
      else
        return nil
      end
    rescue Net::LDAP::LdapError => e
      return nil
    end
  end 
end
```

^This will return my account information if it matches if not it will return nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out my company has a different way of authorizing a user. I added the advanced flag to my devise ldap install, and set this accordingly and presto it worked.

## ==> Advanced LDAP Configuration

```
config.ldap_auth_username_builder = Proc.new() {|attribute, login, ldap| "#{login}@mydomain.com"}
```

Comment: That looks like you are building the UPN which is found on the user's account tab in active directory users and computers.  I needed this for my little project.  In your code above you mention SAMAccount which is the domain\user found on the same tab.